Copy a googlesheet table into email automation how do i keep the same format?
I created a script that can send a table from Google Sheets, but I can't figure out how to keep the same format over that table in email.
Also, does Google work with other email providers to send from Google Sheets, such as Outlook or Apple?
function sendMailWithTable(){
  

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Project Management");

  var bodyEmail = "Hi All, <br/> Please find the weekly summary below. <br/> Highlights are: <br/>"

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var summary = ui.prompt("Please enter this week's update")
  var response = summary.getResponseText()

  var totalRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var totalCols = sheet.getLastColumn();

  var table = "<html><body><br><table border=1>"
  var colVal = "";

  for (var rowNo = 1; rowNo <= totalRows; rowNo ++) {
    table = table +"<tr>"
    for (var colNo =1; colNo <= totalCols; colNo ++) {
      colVal = sheet.getRange(rowNo,colNo).getDisplayValue();
      if(rowNo==1){
        table = table + "<th>" + colVal +"</th>";
      }
      else{
        table = table +"<td>" + colVal +"</td>";
      }
    }
    table = table + '</tr>'
  }

  bodyEmail = bodyEmail + response + table

  MailApp.sendEmail("abe@gmail.com","Weekly Work Log Update","",{htmlBody:bodyEmail});
}

I have this script already ,but how can i keep the same formating? thank you

Hard to do this...

Haha, I know it's hard; I have been trying all day. Do you have any ideas?

Did you checkout the linked question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74424997/how-to-get-the-correct-formatting-in-an-email-when-using-google-sheets-and-app-s

You need to get each attribute like border,font, font size,  text color and background color and then create a equivalent html out of this.
